# Can I edit the powers of my soldier class?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

Can I edit the powers of my soldier class? Add powers from Adept class and remove my basic ammo abilities? Can I do it by editing Coalesced.bin? What I must to do?

Comment: pretty sure you can, just don't play online with that modified file

Answer (score 2):

You can use gibbed mass effect save editor and go in raw->player->power->collection and edit to your heart's content.

Take note however that you CAN'T remove default powers and in order to keep non bonus powers you have to type:

`Set SFXPowerCustomActionBase IsBonusPower true`

in the console every time you start up the game.

It's a pretty crappy work around but I haven't seen anything better yet. They should have added a custom class option to make things more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can edit your Coalesced.bin. Just be careful not to go into multiplayer with an edited Coalesced. You risk getting a ban. Make a copy before you do any editing.

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks_(Mass_Effect_3)#Temporarily_Adding_Any_Power

That's the only workaround I can find. You must re-enable them at game reloads and new mission starts.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without altering the game (possibly causing the need to re-install it)